# Understanding Asycn each

Tags: node.js, asynchronous

I have a function calling async.each over an array. Inside asycn.each there is a function which calls async.each over the data passed in first function.

```
var f1 = function(){
      var b = [o1,o2,o3,o4,o5,o6....];
      async.forEach(b, function(obj, cb){
             f2(obj, function(){
                 cb();
             })
      }, function(err){
      })
};

var f2 = function(obj, c2){
       async.forEach(obj, function(obj2,cb){
          // some db operation
          return dbData;
          cb();
}, function(){
       // do asynch operation on dbData and update value in db
})
};
```

Now, My doubt is, when f2 has done performing async.forEach for 1st item passed in f1, callback is called and callback does some operation with obj, which was passed in f2. But since this is executed parallelly, when 1st item's callback is called, will it have same obj object to continue operation or the value of obj might be different as other asych.each task has been called over same function.

Comment: In f2's forEach, `cb()` is never called because of the `return dbData;`

Answer (score 1):

First your function f1 is executed, after when it completed function f2 is executed.

```
var f1 = function(){
          var b = [o1,o2,o3,o4,o5,o6....];
          async.forEach(b, function(obj, cb){
                 f2(obj, function(){
                     cb();
                 })
          }, function(err){
          })
    };
        async.eachSeries(f1, f2, function (err) {
            if (err) {
                res.json({status: 0, msg: "OOPS! How is this possible?"});
            }
            res.json("Series Processing Done");
        })
       var f2 = function(obj, c2){
           async.forEach(obj, function(obj2,cb){
              // some db operation
              return dbData;
              cb();
    }, function(){
           // do asynch operation on dbData and update value in db
    })
```

Comment: This is not my use case. F1 has to call F2 for each array processing. And once all F2 are processed F1 callback is returned. I just want to know whethere the callback in f2 will get obj which was passed in f1 or some other obj because it is processing parallelly.

Comment: according to my understanding you are going to execute function f1 and then function f2 is executed. these operations performed one after another . first f1 then f2.

Comment: No. This is db operation related to array. I have 10 different obj to update and they all happen simultaneously. So f1 gets 1st obj and then performs operation in f2, similarly other operations. It's not one after another.

Comment: async.series([
    function f1 (){ ... first function executed here then cb from here },
    function f2 (){ ... second function executed here. }
]);
hope this helps.